# FFMPEG - Using multiple Fiters including hardsub, denoise, watermark causes "Too many inputs" Error

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to do one command with complex filters that allow for denoising, hardsub, scaling (to 480 height) and watermark.

I've gotten 3/4 filters to work in combination with each other here:

```
 ffmpeg -i test720.mp4 -vf hqdn3d=1.5:1.5:6:6,scale=w="if(gt(dar\,854/480)\,min(854\,iw*sar)\,2*trunc(iw*sar*oh/ih/2))":h="if(gt(dar\,854/480)\,2*trunc(ih*ow/iw/sar/2)\,min(480\,ih))"\:flags=bicubic,setsar=1\,subtitles=add.ass[out]" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset veryslow -tune film -refs 8 -bf 6 -aq-mode 2  -c:a copy -f mp4 720encoded.mp4
```

but when it comes to all for, it gives me a Too many inputs specified for the "movie" filter.

Here is my command that should work but doesn't :

```
 ffmpeg -i test720.mp4 -vf hqdn3d=1.5:1.5:6:6,scale=w="if(gt(dar\,854/480)\,min(854\,iw*sar)\,2*trunc(iw*sar*oh/ih/2))":h="if(gt(dar\,854/480)\,2*trunc(ih*ow/iw/sar/2)\,min(480\,ih))"\:flags=bicubic,setsar=1\,"movie=actorimage.png[wm];[in][wm]overlay=30:main_h-overlay_h-120\,subtitles=add.ass[out]" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset veryslow -tune film -refs 8 -bf 6 -aq-mode 2  -c:a copy -f mp4 720encoded.mp4
```

I'm sure I'm making a simply syntax error somewhere in there.

Comment: nvm, figured it out. 

 ffmpeg -i test720.mp4 -filter_complex "hqdn3d=1.5:1.5:6:6,scale=w=if(gt(dar\,854/480)\,min(854\,iw*sar)\,2*trunc(iw*sar*oh/ih/2)):h=if(gt(dar\,854/480)\,2*trunc(ih*ow/iw/sar/2)\,min(480\,ih)):flags=bicubic,setsar=1[we];movie=actorimage.png[wm];[we][wm]overlay=30:main_h-overlay_h-120,subtitles=add.ass[out]" -map '[out]' 720.mp4

Comment: Seems like this doesn't get the audio to map out. Anyone have any idea how to get the audio to map out as well?

Comment: Final working script: 'ffmpeg -i test720.mp4 -filter_complex "hqdn3d=1.5:1.5:6:6,scale=w=if(gt(dar\,854/480)\,min(854\,iw*sar)\,2*trunc(iw*sar*oh/ih/2)):h=if(gt(dar\,854/480)\,2*trunc(ih*ow/iw/sar/2)\,min(480\,ih)):flags=bicubic,setsar=1[we];movie=actorimage.png[wm];[we][wm]overlay=30:main_h-overlay_h-120,subtitles=add.ass"  -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset veryslow -tune film -refs 8 -bf 6 -aq-mode 2  -c:a copy -f mp4 720.mp4
'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final working script: `ffmpeg -i test720.mp4 -filter_complex "hqdn3d=1.5:1.5:6:6,scale=w=if(gt(dar\,854/480)\,min(854\,iw‌​sar)\,2*trunc(iwsaro‌​h/ih/2)):h=if(gt(dar‌​\,854/480)\,2*trunc(‌​ihow/iw/sar/2)\,min(‌​480\,ih)):flags=bicu‌​bic,setsar=1[we];mov‌​ie=actorimage.png[wm‌​];[we][wm]overlay=30‌​:main_h-overlay_h-12‌​0,subtitles=add.ass" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset veryslow -tune film -refs 8 -bf 6 -aq-mode 2 -c:a copy -f mp4 720.mp4`